# How to get a simple TCP client working on PIC32 Ethernet starter board?

Tags: tcpclient, ethernet, tcp, pic32

I'm not real network savvy, so I'm struggling with this a bit.  I got the web server demo working okay.  Now I'm trying to construct a client-server connection between a Qt Creator Server on the PC, and a very basic client on the board.  I plagiarized the demo code to init the board and then called tcpOpen() which I expected would fail if it couldn't find the server (Y/N?).
Here's what's enabled in my TCPIPCONFIG.H file:

```
#define STACK_USE_ICMP_SERVER           // Ping query and          
#define STACK_USE_ICMP_CLIENT           // Ping transmission capability
#define STACK_USE_GENERIC_TCP_CLIENT_EXAMPLE    // HTTP Client 
#define STACK_USE_TCP_PERFORMANCE_TEST  // Module for testing TCP TX
```

In main, I have (remember, the functions called from main() were taken from the demo):

```
int main(void)
{
static DWORD t = 0;
static DWORD dwLastIP = 0;

static TCP_SOCKET MySocketClient;

// Initialize application specific hardware
InitializeBoard();

// Initialize stack-related hardware components that may be
// required by the UART configuration routines
TickInit();

// Initialize Stack and application related NV variables into AppConfig.
InitAppConfig();

// Initialize core stack layers (MAC, ARP, TCP, UDP) and
// application modules (HTTP, SNMP, etc.)
StackInit();

// Allocate a socket for this client to try and perform pings
// From the internet: You_need_to_enable STACK_USE_DNS in TCPIPConfig.h to use TCP_OPEN_ROM_HOST
MySocketClient = TCPOpen((DWORD)(PTR_BASE)"169.254.13.41", TCP_OPEN_RAM_HOST, 9999, TCP_PURPOSE_GENERIC_TCP_CLIENT);

if(MySocketClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
{while(1){}};

SOCKET_INFO *remoteSockInfo;
remoteSockInfo = TCPGetRemoteInfo(MySocketClient);

etc.
```

The call to TCPOpen() always returns 0 (which seems to be valid when I inspect remoteSockInfo).  However, it doesn't matter if the ethernet is plugged into the board or not...or whatever IP address I use in that call.

Wouldn't you  expect that call to fail in those circumstances?

Thanks,

Joe B.

PS:  I'm on a company PC trying to test this board, so any network snooping software (like wireshark) are not allowed...I'll be moving to a lab soon and will have more autonomy then.

EDIT:  I found the source code for the GenericTCPClient.c and see that the tcpOpen() call creates the socket and is actively attempting to connect to the server.  So, now I guess my question would be, will the board/socket respond to pings in this state (i.e., not connected to a server yet)?

Answer (score 0):

The board will only respond to Ping if you have enabled Ping in the stack config: (tcpip_config.h)

Edit: I see you enabled it, missed that. I will see what I can dig out of my code that may help.